# Integration by parts in functional field integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, grassmann-numbers

In QFT one often encounters expressions of the form

$$
\displaystyle Z = \int \mathscr{D}(\bar{\psi}, \psi) \, \mathrm{exp} \, S [ \bar{\psi}, \psi ]
$$

with complex-valued (in the bosonic case) or Grassmann-valued (in the fermionic case) integration variables $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$. The action

$$
\displaystyle S[ \bar{\psi}, \psi ] = \sum_{\alpha} \int \mathrm{d} X \, \bar{\psi}_{\alpha}(X) \, G^{\, \operatorname{inv}}_{\alpha, \alpha^{\prime}} (X, X^{\prime}) \, \psi_{\alpha^{\prime}}(X^{\prime})
$$

often includes derivatives of the integration variables ($\psi$ or $\bar{\psi}$) und I often encounter the operation of integration by parts in books in the bosonic cases.

In the bosonic cases I see that it is, at least in some situations, "reasonable" to integrate by parts: In analogy to the heuristics to the Feynman path integral (random phase cancellations there, exponential damping here) the value of the functional field integral is dominated by those configurations that extremize the action. This gives smooth field configurations and the action can indeed be interpreted as integral, being compatible with integration by parts.

How is this in the fermionic case? Can one also integrate by parts in the action there? I have never seen it before, and since there is no meaning of "big" or "small" corresponding to the integrand I don't feel brave enough to just do it without asking.

Comment: The whole apparatus of Berezin integration (i.e. how you define integrals over Grassmann numbers in the first place) has essentially the sole purpose of making integration by parts work by definition.

Comment: But the integration by parts that you refer to is the one inside the Berezin-integral. The one that I am referring to is the one inside the action of the integrand (with respect to $X$ for example). Those are two different things, aren't they?

Comment: Is your question just integration by parts in the functional integral, why we can ignore boundary terms from IbP in the action, or why IbP is allowed in spacetime integrals whose integrands may be Grassman-valued?

Comment: The latter: Why is Integration by parts allowed in spacetime integrals whose integrands are Grassmann-valued. (?) Referring to the discrete version of the integral in the action (as sum) I don't see any reason why it should be reasonable / allowed to shift derivatives.